# Error __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)

Tags: python, django, string, forms, nonetype

I know that this error is classic. But I'm facing a harder problem :

[image]

This is my model. I've check all the topics about this common problem, try to resolve it but I don't achieved. I cannot add stafftimeslot in the admin panel.

Can you help me ?

Here is my models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from staffs.models import Staff
from students.models import Student

TIMESLOT_LIST = (
        (0, '09:00 – 09:30'),
        (1, '09:30 – 10:00'),
        (2, '10:00 – 10:30'),
        (3, '10:30 – 11:00'),
        ...
    )

class StaffTimeSlots(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    time_slot = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TIMESLOT_LIST)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('stafftimeslot_detail', kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

EDIT : When I delete ForeignKey, it works but when I reuse it, it does not work anymore. So I tried to replace with OnetoOneField and ManytoManyField and I have faced with the same problem. It seems that the model does not accept model relations. How can I do to relate this model with the Staff model with a foreign key ?

Comment: Your model only returns a string representation if there's a date set. What happens in case there *isn't* one…!?

Comment: Same problem without the if condition..

Comment: Maybe you have the same thing on those related models too…? Does the stack trace provide any more information which `__str__` exactly it's complaining about…?

Comment: Your original code had a conditional `if self.date is not None:` in the `__str__` method. This would explain why `None` is returned.

Comment: @deceze. I've checked that and I can add Staff and Student models without problems... Where do you want me to check in the stack ?

Comment: @tdelaney, even without the conditional, it does not work..

Comment: *Is* there a trace below what you show in the screenshot and *does* it point to any particular `__str__` method in a specific file and line?

Comment: @deceze I tried to find someting about str or the variables I use to return string or any error in the traceback but I found nothing... I think the problem comes from the ForeignKey field.
I'm importing model from an other app to use it, is there something to do ?

Comment: Ok, I tried to replace Staff with Student and it works. So the problem can come from the Staff model, isn't it ?

Comment: The error is from the _foreign key_ model, if you look at the traceback (which you should have provided the text of instead of that image ) `label_from_instance` is where the error occurs which basically tries to get a label to use for the instance in the select field. Therefore you need to fix `__str__` for the `Staff` model...

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problem.

The problem comes from the Staff model. Here is it :

```
class Staff(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    def __str__(self):
        if self.user is not None:
            return self.user.firstname + " " + self.user.lastname
```

There was not Staff entry in my database inherited from User class . So I add an `else` like this :

```
def __str__(self):
    if self.user is not None:
        return self.user.firstname + " " + self.user.lastname
    else:
        return "Unknown"
```